# Change Collation on SQL server issue

Tags: collation

In order to run an upgrade script I need to change the Collation type from the current to `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS`

I've gone into Properties and Options but when I try to change it I get this error

The Database could not be exclusively locked to perform the operation. `ALTER DATABASE` failed. The default collation of database 'nutri93' cannot be set to `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS`.

I then try to put the database into single user mode with this script

```
ALTER DATABASE nutri93 SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE; 

GO 

ALTER DATABASE nutri93 COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS; 

GO 

ALTER DATABASE nutri93 SET MULTI_USER;
```

But get this error

> Nonqualified transactions are being rolled back. Estimated rollback
>   completion: 100%. Msg 5075, Level 16, State 1, Line 2 The object
>   'Split' is dependent on database collation. The database collation
>   cannot be changed if a schema-bound object depends on it. Remove the
>   dependencies on the database collation and then retry the operation.
>   Msg 5075, Level 16, State 1, Line 2 The object 'CHK_Store_HasURI' is
>   dependent on database collation. The database collation cannot be
>   changed if a schema-bound object depends on it. Remove the
>   dependencies on the database collation and then retry the operation.
>   Msg 5072, Level 16, State 1, Line 2 ALTER DATABASE failed. The default
>   collation of database 'nutri93' cannot be set to
>   SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS.

Any idea how I can resolve this?

Comment: Read the error message: `The object 'CHK_Store_HasURI' is dependent on database collation.` - you need to remove this - and any other objects that depend on the database collation, *then* change the collation, *then* recreate those objects.